# ArgoCD - during set up i deleted argocd-server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, service, argocd

Im currently trying to set up ArgoCD for my 3 Nodes Kuberentes Cluster.
During the set up i made a mistake and falsly deleted the ArgoCD-Server

now how can i get it back ? i cant find the service file to create the argocd-server service

thanks

kubernetesNoob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reinstall ArgoCD with command:

```
kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks i figured that out yesterday !